# Why keywords don't get colored in Remix IDE?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I wrote a code about arrays in solidity.
[image: Array Code]

As shown in the code push(),pop() and length are predefined here. When I tried to change their name it gives an error[image: Push Image Code], same case with other keywords.

If they're keywords why they don't get colored or bold?

Does Remix not a specific function for it unlike other ides(VSCode etc.) .

Comment: Because they are not keywords. They are functions/methods. The reason you are getting an error is because `uint[]` does not have a `pushElement` function. However `DynamicArray` does have a `pushElement` method alas `arr` is not a DynamicArray no matter what the comment says (comment is not code), it is a `uint[]`

Comment: Also, `push()` and `pushElement()` are both colored correctly (light purple?) - because they are functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be supported, but all solidity tooling and the language itself is still a work in progress, and Remix isn't really lying about it either,
Remix says:

> It also provides syntax highlighting mapped to solidity keywords.

And it does, [these](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/cheatsheet.html#reserved-keywords) are the reserved keywords in solidity. Array members like `push()` `pop()` or `length` are not keywords, they are [members](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html?highlight=array#array-members)